# git pre-push-hook - missing build files

Tags: git, githooks

I try to use the pre-push-hook of git to execute a build task before each push. This works fine so far (files get build, added and committed) but the files don't get pushed. Heres the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Pre-Push hook to to build
# files before pushing them.
# If files are in the staging area
# the push aborts.

unstagedFiles=`expr $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null| grep "^ M" | wc -l)`
stagedFiles=`expr $(git diff --cached --numstat | wc -l)`

# if there are unstaged files abort push
if [ "$unstagedFiles" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Pre-Push-Hook: ERROR - You have unstaged files! - please add and commit them"
    exit 1
fi

# if there are staged files abort push
if [ "$stagedFiles" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Pre-Push-Hook: ERROR - You have uncommited files! - please commit them"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Pre-Push-Hook: Building files"
grunt build
echo "Pre-Push-Hook: Files built"

echo "Pre-Push-Hook: Adding following build-files"
git add -A .

git commit -m "automatically added build files"
echo "Pre-Push-Hook: Build-files commited"

exit 0
```

I tried to do another push within the script like this:

```
branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
git push origin $branch --no-verify
exit 1
```

This works quite well but exits of course with an error message which is not really perfect! Does anyone have any ideas to either get the actual push working or to hide the error message when using another push in the script and exiting with 1?

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334493/git-commit-in-pre-push-hook) but the answers left this questions open ...

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: I get following error message which is the the standard message caused by "exit 1" in the hook: 
failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:...'

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your approach correctly, I think you need to pay close attention to the answer provided in your link, particular this bit:

> A pre-push hook is meant as a "verify that this push is OK" operation,
>   not a "change this push to mean some other different push" operation.
>   Use the pre-push hook as a verifier; and if you want a script that
>   invokes git push... write that as a script, using a different name, such as
>   `build-and-push`.

Comment: The goal was to force the developers to make a build before they push their commits and without relying on them to execute a seperate script. I have read this particular section but I thought that I could still use it to accomplish this somehow...