# Push and pull my conda environment using git

Tags: git, github, version-control, conda, environment

I have a git repo with my project. 
I change my `conda` environment quite frequently, so I want my repo to track changes in the environment, and to be able to push the most recent one and pull it in another computer. Is it possible?
I search and find several solutions (e.g. https://tdhopper.com/blog/my-python-environment-workflow-with-conda/) but none provide an automatic changes-tracking.

Meaning, I want to include any changes I make in my environment into the project's repository. Like adding new packages etc. So that when I git pull it in another computer, the new package will be also pulled and added to the environment.

Comment: It might be possible.  Add more details to your question and maybe you will get an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what is missing?

Comment: @okuoub If you have some changes, you commit and push it to github from your machine. Then you use git pull to bring in those changes on your other computer - this is the normal way to use git. But perhaps you are asking about something different - but it is not very clear what you want to accomplish

Comment: @nos I want to include any changes I make in my environment into the project's repository. Like adding new packages, etc. So that when I git pull it in another computer, the new package will be also pulled and added to the environment.

Comment: @okuoub Ok, that's important, so add that to your question. I don't know conda well enough to answer it though.

Answer (score 25):

I use **git hooks** to make conda environment updates automatic. You can have more information on git hooks [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

The idea here is to have two git hooks:

- One which detects if a change in your local conda environment occured and if so, create a new commit with the updated *env.yml* file (I chose a **pre-push** hook for this one).
- One which detects a change in *env.yml* file after a pull (i.e. the remote *env.yml* was different than the local one and was merged, I chose a **post-merge** hook for this one)

As described in the documentation, when a git repository is initiated, a folder *.git/hooks* is created and filled with example scripts. To use one of them, you only have to edit the file, rename it to remove its extension (*.sample*) and make sure it is executable.

**NOTE**: I use zsh as shell but the script should be the same in bash (please comment if not), you would just need to change the shebang line.

---

### pre-push hook

- Rewrite the *pre-push.sample* file already present in *.git/hooks* (replace `<ENV_NAME>` by the name of your conda environment):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

echo "\n==================== pre-push hook ===================="

# Export conda environment to yaml file
conda env export -n <ENV_NAME> > env.yml

# Check if new environment file is different from original 
git diff --exit-code --quiet env.yml 

# If new environment file is different, commit it
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Conda environment not changed. No additional commit."
else
    echo "Conda environment changed. Commiting new env.yml"
    git add env.yml
    git commit -m "Updating conda environment"
    echo 'You need to push again to push additional "Updating conda environment" commit.'
    exit 1
fi
```

- Remove its extension *.sample* and make it executable if necessary (`chmod u+x pre-push`)

---

### post-merge hook

- There were no *post-merge.sample* hook in my *.git/hooks* folder, so I created a file *post-merge* and used this gist https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717 as template:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

echo "\n==================== post-merge hook ===================="

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

echo "Have to update the conda environment"
check_run env.yml "conda env update --file env.yml"
```

- And make it executable (`chmod u+x post-merge`)

---

### What will happen now ?

- When pushing, if the conda environment changed, a message will show that you have to push again to push the commit with the updated *env.yml*
- When pulling, if the pulled *env.yml* differs from the local *env.yml*, conda will update the local environment with the newly pulled *env.yml*.

---

### Limitations

- In case the environment changed locally, you can see that the updated *env.yml* is not automatically pushed to remote. I took the advice from this post [git commit in pre-push hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334493/git-commit-in-pre-push-hook).
- Currently the updating of the conda environment after pull is using a post-merge hook. I don't know how this will be handled in case of `rebase` for example.
- No git expert here, maybe there is hooks better suited for these tasks.
- I noticed a `prefix` section in the *env.yml* which give the path to your environment folder on your local machine. After some test, everything seems to run fine but I don't know if this could somehow create conflicts when developing on various machines.

So ... comments, corrections and ideas of improvements are more than welcome !

Comment: This approach didn't work for me. I get the following output every time I enter `git push`:
==================== pre-push hook ====================
.git/hooks/pre-push: 12: [[: not found
Conda environment changed. Commiting new env.yml
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
You need to push again to push additional "Updating conda environment" commit.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:amorris28/artificial_ecosystem_selection.git'

Comment: I think your line `conda env export -n <ENV_NAME> env.yml` needs a `>` before the `env.yml`

Comment: I think so too, thanks for the comment. I edited accordingly.

Comment: While using this with [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com/#post-merge), the post-merge one takes quite a long time to run. Any idea why?

Comment: I think this might be related to the "conda update" in the post-merge part. Maybe using tools such as [mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/mamba.html) can help speed up the process.

Answer (score 12):

In Conda you can create a virtual environment from and export an environment to a file, which can be included in your git repo. If you pull down your repo on a different machine or delete your environment you can run:

```
conda env create -f=env.yml
```

When you make changes to your environment, run an export before you add/commit:

```
conda env export > env.yml
```