# why does pip export with a different version on subsequent conda env exports?

Tags: python, git, anaconda, environment

I have been trying to establish a pre-commit git hook to detect environment changes and create a new env.yml export automatically ... similar to the ones described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787188)

Where I am having trouble is that the git hook is detecting an environment change with the pip package on every run of the pre-commit file. Is this possibly related to some scripts using different versions of pip?

If so, I don't understand why the same version isn't being exported every time I run `conda env export > env.yml`. It almost seems like it is randomly toggling between versions ... but I know there must be some rationale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conda` and `pip` have their own versions of every package installed (provided that you have installed a certain app using both). `anaconda` (if it's what you're using) is also known for giving plenty of headaches even in simple cases when you `pip install` something instead of `conda install` and start mixing dependencies installed with either of those. The general advice is to be very careful about being consistent with each environment *separately*. In my personal experience, `anaconda` always tries to superimpose itself by by breaking dependencies managed by `pip`. In short, if you are using a `conda` env, make sure that you're using the dependencies installed by `conda` and `conda` only.